# How to wait for setTimeout before each function call?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, settimeout

I need to call a function multiple times with multiple parameters. I want it to be called after the timeout of the previous call is completed. I've tried the following method but it doesn't seem to be working correctly. ([Here's the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uL5gL152/7/)).

Right now it is only waiting after first call. I know it's not the correct way to do this, but I could not find any examples that correctly showed how to do. I will also need to convert it to `typescript`, so please consider that while answering.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="call()">Call all methods</button>

<script>
var myVar;

function call(){
myFunction('normal1','heading1','message1');
myFunction('normal2','heading2','message2');
myFunction('normal3','heading3','message3');

/*Output should be:
(first time dont wait)
heading1 message1
(then wait for timeout and remove the elements)
heading2 message2
(then wait for timeout and remove the elements)
heading3 message3
*/
}

function myFunction(msgType,heading,message) {
console.log(!!document.getElementById("snackbarParent"),document.getElementById('snackbarParent'));
    if(document.getElementById("snackbarParent") == null)
    {
        alertFunc(msgType,heading,message);
    }
    else{
        setTimeout(function(){
        let parent = document.getElementById('snackbarParent');
            parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
            alertFunc(msgType,heading,message);
        },3500);
    }
}

function alertFunc(msgType,heading,message) {

    let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'snackbarParent';
        div.id = "snackbarParent";
        div.innerHTML = '<div id="snackbar"><b style="color:' + msgType + '"> ' + heading + ' </b>' + message + '</div>';

        document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
        // Get the snackbar DIV
        let x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

        // Add the "show" class to DIV
        x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){
        x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
        alert("Should display "+heading+" "+message+" now!");
    }, 3000);

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Note:

The function call() is just for representation purposes. The parameters can have any value and the function myFunction() can be called anytime, anywhere.

Comment: Make a loop.. You are just using 1 function now which puts a delay between going through the whole loop again. Your function now is, 1 (wait 3 secs) 1-2 (wait 3 secs) 1-2-3

Comment: Don't call `myFunction` three times from the `call` function. Call it only once from there and the other two times from the `setTimeout` callback in the `alertFunc` function (in other words, use recursion).

Comment: @Titus @Tomm The function `call()` is just for representation. There can be any number of calls to `myFunction()`. I want to import this functionality to another project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question is marked with `typescript` I'm going to asume that writing this in Typescript is an option.

You could use `async/await` to easily achieve the effect you want while your code maintains a normal look:

```
var myVar;

async function call(){
    await myFunction('normal1', 'heading1', 'message1');
    await myFunction('normal2', 'heading2', 'message2');
    await myFunction('normal3', 'heading3', 'message3');
}
function timeout(delay: number) {
    return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay));
}
async function myFunction(msgType: string, heading: string, message: string) {
    console.log(!!document.getElementById("snackbarParent"), document.getElementById('snackbarParent'));
    if (document.getElementById("snackbarParent") == null) {
        await alertFunc(msgType, heading, message);
    }
    else {
        await timeout(3500);

        let parent = document.getElementById('snackbarParent');
        parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
        await alertFunc(msgType, heading, message);

    }
}

async function  alertFunc(msgType, heading, message) {

    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'snackbarParent';
    div.id = "snackbarParent";
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="snackbar"><b style="color:' + msgType + '"> ' + heading + ' </b>' + message + '</div>';

    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    // Get the snackbar DIV
    let x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

    // Add the "show" class to DIV
    x.className = "show";
    await timeout(3000);
    x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
    alert("Should display " + heading + " " + message + " now!");

}
```

**Note**: If you don't want typescript, babel also has support for `async/await` but you will still need a transpiler.

**Note** To compile for `es5` with `async/await` you will need a `Priomise` library if promises aren't in the environment, and you can use the flowing tconfig.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
        "es5",
        "es2015.promise",
        "dom"
    ]
}
```

A pure js approach could use an `onDone` callback to have a way to notify the caller of when the function really completed. This is better that to add the code directly in `alertFunc` as other answers suggest as that will make `alertFunc` less reusable:

```
function call() {
    myFunction('normal1', 'heading1', 'message1', function () {
        myFunction('normal2', 'heading2', 'message2', function () {
            myFunction('normal3', 'heading3', 'message3', function () {
                // DOne
            });
        });
    });
}
function myFunction(msgType, heading, message, onDone) {
    console.log(!!document.getElementById("snackbarParent"), document.getElementById('snackbarParent'));
    if (document.getElementById("snackbarParent") == null) {
        alertFunc(msgType, heading, message, onDone);
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var parent = document.getElementById('snackbarParent');
            parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
            alertFunc(msgType, heading, message, onDone);
        }, 3500);
    }
}
function alertFunc(msgType, heading, message, onDone) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'snackbarParent';
    div.id = "snackbarParent";
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="snackbar"><b style="color:' + msgType + '"> ' + heading + ' </b>' + message + '</div>';
    document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
    // Get the snackbar DIV
    var x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
    // Add the "show" class to DIV
    x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function () {
        x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
        alert("Should display " + heading + " " + message + " now!");
        if (onDone)
            onDone();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Async-Await is supported only when targeting ECMAScript 2015 or higher. We are using es5.

Comment: @SanjuAus Not true, don't remember when support for es5 was added but it is there, you may need a promise library, but you can target es5

Comment: But I get error, `TS1311: Async functions are only available when targeting ECMAScript 2015 or higher.`

Comment: check your ts version

Comment: @SanjuAus Also added a JS version, but I still say the TS `async/await` looks much better :)

Comment: I'm using typescript 2.0.3 and I don't think I can update it as of now(breaking changes). However I tried the javascript solution. But how do I implement it when number of calls to myFunction() is unknown? (The implementation I'm looking for is like *queue*).

Comment: There can be any number of invocations and invocations can be done at anytime (it need not be one after another), it depends on developers using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161201/discussion-between-titian-cernicova-dragomir-and-sanjuaus).

Comment: The solution throws error `onDone is not a function` in javascript, but it is working when converted to typescript without branching `myFunction()` call. Thank you!

Comment: I think I have a version that will work for you : https://jsfiddle.net/h0jwkbvs/1/#&togetherjs=5E9dE3Oszv

Answer (score 2):

```js
var massages = [];
massages[0] = ['normal1','heading1','message1'];
massages[1] = ['normal2','heading2','message2'];
massages[2] = ['normal3','heading3','message3'];

function settime(i){
setTimeout(fn,3000,i)
}
function fn(i){
    var heading = massages[i][1],
          message = massages[i][2],
            msgType = massages[i][0];
            let x = document.getElementById("snackbar");
           x.innerHTML = '<div id="snackbar"><b style="color:' + msgType + '"> ' + heading + ' </b>' + message + '</div>';
        alert("Should display "+heading+" "+message+" now!");
    if(i<massages.length-1) {i++;settime(i)};
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>

<button onclick="settime(0)">Try it</button>
<div id='snackbar'></div>
```

Comment: How do we implement this when array of messages is unknown?

Comment: the array of massages must be defined before first call method and can change during process, even timeout called its check the global i variable that is less than massages length;

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
function callMe(yourParam){
//you can conditionly modify your param 
//if (somecondition)
// newParam=yourPram ... 
setTimeout(()=>callMe(newParam),1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is not nice approach to perform it but in this case, you couldn't call `myFunction` function consecutively because `setTimeout` runs asynchronous and don't block the thread. So, modify `alertFunc` like this;

```
function alertFunc(msgType,heading,message) {

    let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.className = 'snackbarParent';
        div.id = "snackbarParent";
        div.innerHTML = '<div id="snackbar"><b style="color:' + msgType + '"> ' + heading + ' </b>' + message + '</div>';

        document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
        // Get the snackbar DIV
        let x = document.getElementById("snackbar");

        // Add the "show" class to DIV
        x.className = "show";
    setTimeout(function(){
            if(msgType == "normal1")
            {
                 myFunction('normal2','heading2','message2');//Call second function after first one completed
            }
            if(msgType == "normal2")
            {
                 myFunction('normal3','heading3','message3');//Call third function after second one completed
            }
        x.className = x.className.replace("show", "");
        alert("Should display "+heading+" "+message+" now!");
    }, 3000);

}
```

And the Call function looks like;

```
function call(){
   myFunction('normal1','heading1','message1'); //Just call first function in the beginning
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned in comment, the function call() is just for representation purposes. The parameters can have any value.